# download Ethereum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

the blockchain now has 6,170,500 blocks. To speed up the download I'm using the method at https://mudra.cloud/ethereum/blockchain.html   Is this the fastest method? Does anyone know another faster method? Thanks